# PyInstaller: ImportError DLL load failed while importing _socket

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, windows-7, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a standalone executable using PyInstaller but I'm encountering an issue related to the multiprocessing module and the socket module. When running the compiled application, I get the following error:

I'm using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import "numpy.core._dtype_ctypes" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.dbc" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.arxml" --hidden-import "asammdf.blocks.cutils" --hidden-import "psutil" --additional-hooks-dir=hooks --onefile --noconsole --icon "C:\Program Files (x86)\img\DEMO.ico" --uac-admin --name "Extractor" python_eel.py
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myenv38_64\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 109, in <module>
  File "myenv38_64\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 18, in _pyi_rthook
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "socket.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The parameter is incorrect.
```

This works well on Windows 10 and some Windows 7 laptops but doesn't work on a particular Windows 7 laptop. Why?
Can anyone help, please?